# Using rsync4j library, a Java implementation of Linux rsync tool, how to sync data from a remote directory with a local directory

Tags: java, rsync, librsync

I need the functionality like that of the **`rsync`** linux tool in my Java program. For that, I chose the [rsync4j library](https://github.com/fracpete/rsync4j).

Using their [documentation](https://github.com/fracpete/rsync4j/blob/master/docs/java.md), I wrote the following program:

```
import com.github.fracpete.processoutput4j.output.ConsoleOutputProcessOutput;
import com.github.fracpete.rsync4j.RSync;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        System.out.println("Started");//check

        RSync rsync = new RSync()
            .source("/home/arth/DataSourceFolder/a.txt")
            .destination("/home/arth/DataDestinationFolder/")
            .recursive(true);
            // or if you prefer using commandline options:
            // rsync.setOptions(new String[]{"-r", "/one/place/", "/other/place/"});
            CollectingProcessOutput output = null;
            try {
                    System.out.println("Inside try");
                    output = rsync.execute();
                    System.out.println("End of try");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(output.getStdOut());
            System.out.println("Exit code: " + output.getExitCode());
            if (output.getExitCode() > 0)
                System.err.println(output.getStdErr());
      }
}
```

In the snippet, in out local machine, a file `a.txt` is copied from one location to another. This works perfectly. The file is successfully copied when I run it and here is the output:

```
Started

Inside try

End of try

Exit code: 0
```

But my need is to sync a local directory with a directory lying at a remote host/machine. When I tried to do it using a simple `rsync` command from a terminal using the following command

```
rsync remoteUserName@23.24.25.244:/home/beth/remoteFolder/a.png /home/arth/DataSourceFolder
```

it works like a charm. `a.png` IS copied to local machine at path specified, although a password of remote machine is asked first.

**But the problem when I use the above Java program to do the same operation, by replacing line # 11 and 12 by:**

```
.source("remoteUserName@23.24.25.244:/home/beth/remoteFolder/a.png")
.destination("/home/arth/DataDestinationFolder/")
```

**the program gets stuck after printing `Started` in the console. Neither an exception is thrown nor does the program proceed.**

The question is that how do I fix this problem?

Comment: Were you ever able to get a solution for this? Providing the password programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

(old post, I know, but here it goes...) The rsync4j library does not allow interaction. In your case, the underlying rysnc binary prompts for a password in the process that the Java library created, but never receives one.

Starting with release [3.2.3-7](https://github.com/fracpete/rsync4j/releases/tag/rsync4j-pom-3.2.3-7), you can supply an instance of the `sshpass` wrapper to feed in the password (see [this comment](https://github.com/fracpete/rsync4j/issues/21#issuecomment-923272241) for an example).